# Down right arrow similar to \to

Tags: arrows, math-operators

I want an arrow of the same size and style as the `\to` arrow, but first going down and then right, similar to this:

[image: down right arrow].

Until now I just have managed to do:
`\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\Lsh$}`
But it is not really so nice looking.

Is there an easy way to do this? Shouldn't it be part of the standard LaTeX arrows, for mathematical formulas, where something is implied in the next line?

Comment: You can always use tikz or similar to draw the arrow, or perhaps even use includegraphics to include an arrow made with a program like paint or photoshop. With existing symbols I'm unaware of anything that would look better than `\Lsh` or `\Rsh`.

Comment: What about `\drsh` from the [mathabx package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathabx)?